# SQL pulling data from multiple tables to one table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-insert

I have a massive database (over 200 tables) and need to pull data from different ones to a new one. I am also hard coding some of the data using values as they are not stored within the database.

I understand pretty simple SQL however am struggling with the more advanced stuff. From researching I have found it is most likely going to work with the join command, however after a few tries I have been unsuccessful.

I was hoping if somebody could point me in the right direction to extend my research or to put me on the right tracks if the join isn't right. Not asking for this to be done for me just some pointers as I feel all I have tried have failed.

A brief example may also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need a JOIN if the data can join together, or a union if the data is in similar data in different tables. It will be very hard to help without at least some better ideas of what you're trying to do. Could you maybe provide some example data? Make sure to scrub the data before posting it online.

A great place to learn: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: How do you mean if the data can join together?

Its hard to explain the data and is sensitive so cannot directly share it.
basically its all different data types from different tables, to be put in a table that is already made with columns defined

Comment: I understand the data is sensitive, I have the same problem with my data at work and needing help.

Is there a key in one table that is a Foreign Key in another table? That is how it would join. Say you have two tables both have a last name in them, you could join on that field.

Comment: Is it possible to join on something that isnt going to be inserted into the new table? As there is corresponding data that but not that i'm using?

Comment: @ChrisG:  yes, you can join on fields that aren't going to be inserted into the new table.